# Create a filter-type table with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have three different divs that's returning data via JSON. Here's what it looks like with three plain html divs next to each other: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq8yg.png

Is it possible to make this table a bit more dynamic, for instance if I click on a "90" value, the corresponding options to the right appear (40 and 599 as well as 10 and 399)

In more simple terms, I wish to clean this table up a bit and make it more presentable - instead of displaying everything at once, I wish to have the user only see the values they wish to see, through radio buttons or something.

Comment: You could map your data into an array and then filter that array using the fliter pipe in angular [filter pipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), it depends a lot on your json data

Comment: Well, for now I've just put it in a $scope like so:


    `$scope.values = [
        
            {:"599","40", "90"},
            {"399",data"10", "90"},
 
            ];`